Can I feed a whole squid to my gar?
Question: Can gars be fed whole squids?
I assume only frozen is alright in order to get rid of parasites.

please edit a bit more information into your question,like the size of your fish and the size of the squid you want to feed to your fish.

@trondhansen my question is more-or-less in regards to if squids are safe for gars to eat. I can remove any extra food (if the squid is too big—although I doubt this).
